# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US Floreant POS

Tags: java, maven, internationalization

I have downloaded the FLoreant POS open source code,  using mvn clean install it got build successfully. But when I am trying to run the application its not able to read the `messages.properties` file even though everything is in classpath below is the structure of project and classpath snapshot. not getting any clue why input Stream is coming as null in code

```
private static class ResourceControl extends ResourceBundle.Control {
        @Override
        public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload) throws IllegalAccessException,
                InstantiationException, IOException {
            String bundlename = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
            String resName = toResourceName(bundlename, "properties"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resName);
            return new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

    }
```

[image]

[image]

maven build plugin code

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.code.sf.net/p/floreantpos/code/trunk</connection>
</scm>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>floreantpos</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>filters</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.floreantpos.main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>config/ i18n/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>resources/META-INF/mvn-assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="prepare phase" />
                            <unzip src="database/derby-server/posdb.zip" dest="${project.build.directory}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-1.4-build${buildNumber}.zip" basedir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-bin/${project.build.finalName}"></zip>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-antrun-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.6,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Maven doesn't care about your eclipse build path. It's resources plugin is configured to copy resources from src and resources, and properties files from filters

Comment: @JBNizet that means do i need to include i18n folder also to include properties file

Answer (score 0):

Just copy "i18n" directory from src to target/floreantpos-bin directory. 
Run your application from target/floreantpos-bin directory using

```js
java -jar floreantpos.jar
```